# How to install CPU Sim

Tags: software-installation

I have recently switched from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 12.04. I want to know how to install CPU Sim 3.9.0 in Ubuntu.

What are the commands in terminal used for installing.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Is it this [CPU Sim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_Sim) you are talking about?

Comment: yes,thatwhat i m talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## How to install CPU Sim 3.9.0

Open a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>. Download the CPUSim-Zipfile:

```
wget http://www.cs.colby.edu/djskrien/CPUSim/CPUSim3.9.0.zip
```

Install unzip

```
sudo apt-get install unzip
```

Unzip the CPUSim3.9.0.zip-file

```
unzip CPUSim3.9.0.zip
```

Go into the newly created folder

```
cd CPUSim3.9.0/
```

If you haven't install a Java JRE or JDK yet, you need to install it now. If you are unsure write `java -version`. if this results with an error you must install it.

You need to first enable the [universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository). Then you can install the Java Runtime Environment (JRE).

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```

Create an executable start script

```
cat <<'EOF' > cpusim
#!/bin/bash
java -cp CPUSim3.9.jar:jhall.jar:CPUSimHelp3.9.jar cpusim.Main -m SampleAssignments/Wombat1.cpu -t SampleAssignments/W1-0.a
EOF
chmod +x cpusim
```

Execute the script to run CPU Sim 3.9.0

```
./cpusim
```